# Cauchy-Goursat theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

I understand the solution to this question via the use of the following corollary

[image]

However for $k+1=0$ you get :

$\displaystyle \oint_0^{2\pi}id\theta$

Why am I not able to apply the cauchy-goursat theorem to get that the integral=0?

Answer (score 2):

There's no contradiction, you just proved $z^{-1}$ doesn't have a primitive function on any open set containing $\gamma_1$.

$(z^n)'=nz^{n-1}$ gives you a primitive function of $z^{n-1}$ only for $n\ne0$, so $z^{-1}$ is excluded. You could think of using the principal branch of the complex logarithm, but that's not even continuous on $\gamma_1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it if $k\geq 0$ (because $z\mapsto z^k$ is holomorphic on $\gamma \cup\operatorname{int}(\gamma )$, but not for $k<0$, because the function is not holomorphic on all of $\Omega$ because there is a singularity in $z=0\in\gamma \cup\operatorname{int}(\gamma )$. For example, for $k=-1$, by using the Cauchy formula you get:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i.$$

**remark:** You can't apply your corollary here, because $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ is not continuous on $\Omega$ (because it's not continuous in $z=0$)

Comment: But $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z^2}$ is not continuous at $z=0$ ,so you can't apply the corollary there either?

Comment: * You can't apply the corollary in the case $f(z)=z^k; \space$ $k<0$?

Comment: Exactly ! For all $k<0$ you can't apply the corollary.

Comment: I understand you can't use Cauchy Goursat for $k<0$. But the solution does apply the **corollary** for all $k+1 \neq 0$; i.e $k<0 \space ;k+1 \neq 0$. Does $f$ have to only be continuous on $\gamma$?

Comment: It's not because for all $k<-1$ the integral is nul that you can use the corollary. Actually is a consequence of the residues theorem (or if you don't know this theorem, you can also use the generalization of Cauchy formula which is a particular case of the residues theorem). For all $k<-1$, $\text{res}(z\mapsto z^k)=0$ then $\int_\gamma z^kdz=2\pi i\cdot \text{res}(z\mapsto z^k)=0$. Do you understand ? If your solution does apply this corollary, then your solution is wrong (even if the results are the same).

Comment: That is confusing. I would have thought that as we are integrating on the curve $\gamma $ it would only matter whether or not $f$ was continuous on $\gamma$. Is this something to do with the curve being closed? I have a solution to the same question but where the curve is not closed (integrating between $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$) and because the contour does not intersect $z=0$, I can use $F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. You of course CAN apply the corollary for $k < -1$. Eg. $-z^{-1}$ is a primitive function to $z^{-2}$ on the open set $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ containing $\gamma_1$. Also is it really a corollary of Cauchy's integral theorem? This can be proven quite easily without any heavy theory.